# How to contact AirAsia?

Tags: airasia

Trying to contact Airasia, but I cannot find a phone number (no voice mail service). The chat support is with a bot which is not helpful. If you have any experience contacting them, can you share your experience? I am really frustrated. I also left messages on their voicemail system no one has returned my call.

Comment: Go to airport and yell at them?

Comment: @AnishSheela even at the Airport they say to contact customer service which does not exist. lol

Comment: May be you missed the yelling part. Air Asia cuts customer service to the bare minimum and to lowest quality. That's how prices remains low.